# Python: How would one represent this particular for loop using list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

As the title states, I would like to know how to use "list comprehension" to shorten this for loop. The loop is functional; however, the details of the assignment given to me states that I should have at least one list comprehension and this was the only for loop in my code. By the way, I am fairly new to python.

```
z=0
for elements in a
    if a[z] in c:
        z=z+1
    elif a[z] in b:
        c.append(a[z])
        z=z+1
    else:
        z=z+1
```

Also, if there are any general tips to shorten this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: your `for` loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: What's going on with your `pass`?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R The only for loops I have done were to apply a function to a set. So, I attempted to write (elements for elements in a if a[z] in c...); however, I did not understand how to pass the "pass" or "z=z+1" commands into the list comprehension behind my if statement.

Comment: @Will I was told that the pass skipped all other statements in the for loop.

Comment: `pass` is a null operation, it won't interrupt the flow

Comment: @Kerry M-R Alright. So, I should just take that out?

Comment: `continue` is what skips an iteration of the loop. but if you put a `continue` there then `z=z+1` wouldn't happen.

Comment: @Will Oh, okay. Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want is to take elements from `a` and place them in `c` if those elements are present in `b`. Also you want to make sure that only one such element exits in `c`, meaning `c` is a set.

You can do that as

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 3]
>>> b = [3, 5]
>>> set([ i for i in a if i in b ])
set([3, 5])
```

Comment: So, cut the z variable, and use set(). Awesome, thank you. Would you know how to get rid of  any possible duplicates?

Comment: The `set()` will remove any duplicates. Experiment a bit with the list comprehension. Try removing the `set`

Comment: Cool. It looks so much neater. Thank you. And I will do my best to experiment. :)

Comment: @Noaline All the best :)